# create an object depending on the caller object

Tags: c#, methods, polymorphism

I have many classes in a program but almost all of them have the same methods and call almost the same stored procedures in a SQL Server. The difference in the name is the name of the class ( "pa" + class + CRUD). Is there a way to create a common calling method?

I want to make a method that, called from, let's say, the Student class, would call "paStudentSelect" and return a Student object; and if the method is called from the Teacher class the called SP is "paTeacherSelect" and return a Teacher object.

Extra: I have to check for nulls that vary from class to class. Using a string array as a parameter would be possible to check the properties of the class named in the string array?

PS: I know the thing to do is refactor and think again the code, the tables and the SPs but it's not my program.

Comment: Note that if you have a base class `Base` and a derived class `Derived`, it is not clear whether you want `Base base = new Derived(); base.CallCRUD();` to use `paBaseCRUD` or `paDerivedCRUD`. The first two answers given resolve this ambiguity in different ways.

Comment: @RaymondChen I think I didn't explain myself too well. The idea is to have a base (abstract?) class from where almost all other classes inherit and those classes have to call the SPs with the name structure I said.

Comment: Right. But what if multiple names apply? Suppose you have a `Person` class and a `Teacher` class which derives from `Person`. If you call `person.CallCRUD()`, and the person happens to be a teacher, do you want to use `paPersonSelect` or `paTeacherSelect`?

Answer (score 0):

1. As you've described your class name, this should do it:

   ```
   var proc_name = string.Format("pa{0}delete", GetType().Name);
   ```
2. Extra:  yes.  Using reflection you can get a `PropertyDescriptor` for the class named in the string array or, if you want, the `Type` array...

   ```
   var types = new Type[] { typeof(Student), typeof(Teacher), ... };
   foreach(var t types) 
   {
       // todo: perform your null checks here

       var proc_name = t.Name;
       db.ExecuteSQLCommandOrWhatever(proc_name);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to do such a thing. You say that you want to be able to call a common method from different classes(Student, Teacher, etc). If you were calling the method from a common place it made more sense to create a common method but when you are actually calling the method from the classes themselves you might as well call the appropriate SP and avoid the pitfalls with the type of approach you should take(code breaks with name changes and possibly more).

If you absolutely have to do this I can think of two possible solutions:

**1) Extension Methods:** create a common abstact type(you probably have one already) for your classes and add an extension method for that abstract class. The method could be something like this:

```
protected void CallCRUD(this AbstractType obj)
{
    //call SP on this.TableName
}
```

**2) Generic Method:** create a static generic method:

```
public static T CallCRUD<T>()
{
    //call SP on typeof(T).Name
}
```

Your "Extra:" is very vague so I don't have an answer for you there.

Comment: The problem is that almost every class is cut-and-paste from another class. There's no inheritance. What I want to do is make a Base class and inherit all those from Base. The problem is that each class calls an SP that follows the same name structure ("pa"+class+C/R/U/D) and have different parameters.

Comment: @bufalo1973 I do not see the reason why different classes have different parameters for CRUD operations ! You fill the object and ask it to be updated, saved(C and U). You read the content of an object and fill it in(C). You don't need parameters at all ! Anyhow, it seems like in order for you to achieve this you need some tidying up to do. Otherwise, if you want to handle different parameters you can create an abstraction that is able to contain different sets of parameters and then pass that abstraction as a single argument to the methods.